# Can a penalty kick be passed to a second player?

Tags: rules, football

Is it possible for the penalty to be played by two players as a passed ball? Means the first player can pass the ball to the second player who will kick the ball in the goal.

Comment: For an example of how such a penalty can be (legally) scored, see this penalty taken by Johan Cruijff, who passes the ball to Jesper Olsen: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MJHN1mN5SCg

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is allowed. However, the procedure on pages 45 - 48 of the [2015/16 FIFA Laws of the Game](http://www.fifa.com/development/education-and-technical/referees/laws-of-the-game.html) must be adhered to. The main points are:

- All players other than the first kicker and goalkeeper must remain outside the penalty area and penalty arc and behind the ball until the ball is kicked.
- The goalkeeper must have part of each foot on or above the goal line until the ball is kicked.
- The ball must be kicked forwards.
- The first kicker must be identified.
- If both teams infringe the above conditions, or only the defending team infringes, a retake will occur as soon as the second kicker touches the ball (ie. when the penalty kick is over).
- If only the attacking team infringes, the defending team will be awarded an indirect free kick from position of whichever infringement was closest to the attacking team's goal as soon as the second kicker touches the ball (ie. when the penalty kick is over).